# Metrics for cluster evaluation

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I make a set of clusters using some clustering algorithm. Precision, Recall, F Measure, Fallout and RI of individual clusters are calculated for testing the performance. How do I calculate the average precision, recall, f measure, etc.? Is it the average of the different clusters' precisions? How do I get a single precision number for the *N* total clusters?

Answer (score 1):

Please do some more literature research on cluster evaluation.

Precision and Recall are computed differently than in classification, as a clustering algorithm may yield a different number of classes, and there is no 1:1 correspondence.

Pair-counting measures are the most common approach, and there is no need for averaging in these measures.

Comment: What are pair-counting measures? How to calculate them

Comment: See Wikipedia, or a book on cluster analysis... You may want to read up on ARI, the Adjusted Rand Index.